# Shortcut to extract flutter widget into a new file

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I use Android Studio. I have a few Flutter widgets in one file. Is it a way to extract a widget into its own DART file very quickly, like a shortcut?

For example, how to extract HomePage from such a file?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'my_chart.dart';
import 'my_schedule.dart';
import 'my_slider.dart';

void main() => runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MySchedule(),
      child: HomePage(),
    ));

// TODO extract HomePage to a new file via a shortcut
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(
            child: Text('Change Piechart Dynamically'),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: MyChart(),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: MySlider(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You propably extracted the widgets from your Widget Tree into extra Classes by using the extract widget function.
While I haven't found a shortcut to extract the already made class to a new file, by installing the ['Flutter Enhancement Suite' plugin by Marius Höfler](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12693-flutter-enhancement-suite) you will get a shortcut to extract the widget into a new file directly: `CTRL`+`ALT`+`E`

Comment: I can't find this shortcut. Neither in Android Studio (https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts), nor in IntelliJ (https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf). Do you use Visual Studio?

Comment: That is quite interesting. No, I am using Android Studio too. Please try the following: choose a widget in your widget tree `right click`->`Refactor`->`Extract Widget to File`. It should also tell you the shortcut at the end of the line.

Comment: What do you mean by "widget tree"? `Flutter Outline`? If yes, then there's no `right click -> Refactor` there. This is possible only when clicking on a widget name in the code itself. And there's no `Extract Widget to File` afterwards. 

Mine Android Studio version is `2020.3.1 Patch 3`

Comment: I finally found it! After disabling all plugins one after another I found that this feature got added via the ['Flutter Enhancement Suite' plugin by Marius Höfler](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12693-flutter-enhancement-suite)

Comment: nice research :)

Answer (score -1):

The New Shortcut Key to Extract Widget In Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1  is **Ctrl + Alt + E**